# Databricks scala remove intermittent \n from a data frame field

Tags: scala, databricks

In scala I have a dataframe that has a string field and in this field some rows' values have intermittent line-feed (\n) characters.
All I want to do is end up with a version of the dataframe simply with remove the '\n's removed.

```
command-358622955667885:15: error: value replace is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column
    var t2df = tdf.withColumn("qty", tdf("Quantity").replace("\n","")).drop(m)
                                        ^

command-358622955667885:16: error: not found: value replace
    var t2df = tdf.withColumn("qty", replace(tdf("Quantity"), "\n", "")).drop(m)
                                     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
t2df = t2df.withColumn("qty2", regexp_replace(col("qty"), "[\\r]", "")).drop("qty").withColumnRenamed("qty2","qty")
```

But why do you have to use regex?

Why can I use a simple replace?